# Migrating from Browserify to Webpack inside Gulp Task

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

I`m very new to automation tasks, so I might be a little off road here. I have a gulp tasks which uses Browserify to build up my core JS files.

```
/*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

var args = require('yargs').argv,
   bowerJson = require('../../bower.json'),
   del = require('del'),
   gulp = require('gulp'),
   jsmerge = require('./jsmerge'),
   logger = require('@slomka/gulp-logger'),
   run = require('gulp-run'),
   runSequence = require('run-sequence');
   webpack = require('webpack');

var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

var webAppFolder = './slomka.Gx.Web.App';
var bundles = [
   webAppFolder + '/JavaScript/Namespacing.js',
   webAppFolder + '/JavaScript/slomka.Utils.js',
   webAppFolder + '/JavaScript/slomka.Editor.js',
   webAppFolder + '/JavaScript/slomka.DocumentEditor.js'
];
var slomkaCoreJs = [
   'JavaScript/slomka.Config.js',
   'JavaScript/slomka.Error.js',
   'JavaScript/slomka.Polyfill.js',
   'JavaScript/slomka.Validator.js',
   'JavaScript/3rdParty/telerik.js',
   'JavaScript/3rdParty/Kendo.all.min.js',
   'JavaScript/FileLinks.js',
   'JavaScript/ColorPicker.js',
   'Javascript/ButtonUtils.js',
   'JavaScript/slomka.Kendo.js',
   'JavaScript/slomka.Resource.Review.js',
   'JavaScript/slomka.Resource.Section.js',
   'JavaScript/FeatureDecisions.js',
   'App_GxPages/MasterPages/header.ascx.js'
];

gulp.task('js:core:clean', function () {
   return del(webAppFolder + '/static/js/core.*');
});

gulp.task('js:core:thirdparty:clean', function () {
   return del(webAppFolder + '/static/js/thirdparty.min.*');
});

gulp.task('js:core:thirdparty', ['js:core:thirdparty:static'], function () {
   const wiredep = require('wiredep');

   return jsmerge(
      gulp, [
         gulp.src(wiredep({ bowerJson: bowerJson, directory: webAppFolder + '/bower_components' }).js),
         gulp.src([
            'node_modules/@gx/test-table-execution/dist/*.js',
            'node_modules/@gx/columnresize/dist/*.js',
            'node_modules/@gx/ddt/dist/*.js',
            'node_modules/@gx/jquery-contextmenu/dist/*.js',
            'node_modules/@gx/legacy-history-dialog/dist/*.js',
            'node_modules/@slomka/javascript-detect-element-resize/jquery.resize.js',
            'node_modules/@slomka/slomka-sticky-headers/dist/slomka-sticky-headers.js'
         ])
      ],
      'thirdparty.min.js',
      webAppFolder + '/static/js',
      true,
      logger('js:core:thirdparty')
   )();
});

gulp.task('js:core:thirdparty:static', ['js:core:thirdparty:static:clean'], function () {
   var copyitem = 'copy-item .\\node_modules\\@gx\\*\\dist\\static\\ .\\slomka.Gx.Web.App\\static\\thirdparty\\ -recurse -force';
   return run(copyitem, { usePowerShell: true }).exec();
});

gulp.task('js:core:thirdparty:static:clean', function () {
   return del(webAppFolder + '/static/thirdparty/**');
});

gulp.task('js:core', ['js:core:clean'], function () {
   

   if (!args.production)
      runSequence('js:lint');

   var thirdpartySource = gulp.src('thirdparty.min.js', { cwd: webAppFolder + '/static/js' });
   var coreSource = gulp.src(slomkaCoreJs, { cwd: webAppFolder });

   var bundledSource = browserify({
      entries: bundles
   })
      .transform('babelify',{ global: true })
      .transform('envify', {
         global: true,
         NODE_ENV: args.production ? 'production' : 'development'
      })
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('bundled.js'));

   return jsmerge(
      gulp, [thirdpartySource, bundledSource, coreSource],
      'core.js',
      webAppFolder + '/static/js',
      false,
      logger('js:core')
   )();
});

gulp.task('js:core:watch', function () {
   gulp.watch(slomkaCoreJs, { cwd: webAppFolder }, ['js:core']);
});
```

Now I'm trying to remove browserify and add webpack to do this building. But I'm having issues trying to bundle them all together. The goal of using webpack is not the bundle itself I'm migrating to use handlebars templates on other stuff.

In this case, I have a few questions:

- In my webpack.config.js would I need to hardcode every JS file? For instance

  ```
    const path = require('path');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    var webAppFolder = './slomka.Gx.Web.App';
    module.exports = {
      context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      entry: {
        thirdparty: './../static/js/thirdparty.min.js',
        namespacing:  webAppFolder + '/JavaScript/Namespacing.js',
        utils: webAppFolder + '/JavaScript/slomka.Utils.js',
        .... etc for the rest..
      },
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      },
    };
  ```
- Would I need to configure a pipe for babelify or Webpack can handle that for me? I tried adding this configuration for my webpack config.

  ```
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  ```
- After migrating to webpack, I would have the hot change watch?